# jQuery change the dragged element on the fly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

What I need is to replace the dragging element with another div, I tried the helper:"clone", also the custom helper, all the solutions I've tried so far are really buggy.

I need to do this to drag 'n' drop the fiches on the green carpet.
[css/javascript/html roulette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0lTX.png)

```js
function createFiche(id) {
    $(id).draggable({
          start: function(event, ui) {
            if (!this.classList.contains("dragged")) {
              var $div = $(this).clone();
              var offset = $(this).offset();
              var xPos = event.pageX - offset.left - $(this).width() / 4.5; //calculates the center
              var yPos = event.pageY - offset.top - $(this).height() / 4.5; //calculates the center
              this.id = "";
              this.classList.add("dragged");
              $(this).css({
                "margin-top": yPos + "px",
                "margin-left": xPos + "px",
                "z-index": fiches + topZindex
              }); //centers it
              fiches++;
              $div.appendTo($("#fiches"));
              createFiche(id);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify?  You are dragging one `<div>` and part way through you want to stop dragging that `<div>` and drag a different `<div>`?  Or...?  Can you show code you have tried?

Comment: sure but I dont know how to post the code here :/ I'll use pastebin

Comment: For reference, see [How Do I Format My Code Blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @JohnHascall Yeah, basically I need to replace the fiche in the bar with anotherone when I drag the fiche in the hotbar on the green carpet. What I want is that this happens without the user sees that "swap".

Comment: @4TheGame3 I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. Maybe you can put a new element at the current position of helper, but it can't be further dragged, because drag (mouse click + mouse move) didn't happen on that new element.